# Estimating $\sum k^3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am given the following theorem :

If $f(x) > 0$ $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x) >0$ for $ 1\le x < \infty $ then

$$0 \le \sum_1^nf(k) - \int_1^n f - \frac{1}{2}f(n)-\frac{1}{2}f(1) \le \frac{1}{4}f'(n)$$

Applying the condition to $\sum_1^n k^3$ We end up with

$$0 \le \sum_1^n f(k) - (\frac{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+1}{4})\le 0$$

However we are well aware from the formula that $$\sum_1^nk^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$$

Which isn't equal to what the theorem says. Confused.

Comment: The theorem only gives a bound, and indeed $n^4+2n^3+n^2\leq n^4+2n^3+3n^2+1$. (The first expression is $n^2(n+1)^2$.)

Comment: If you've subtracted the $f'(n)/4$ from the right, then you don't still have $0\leq $ on the left.

Comment: No reaction to the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem states:

$$0\leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 - \frac{n^4+2n^3+1}{4}\leq \frac{3n^2}{4}$$

If you then subtract $\frac{3n^2}{4}$, you have to do so for *all* the terms, giving you:

$$\frac{-3n^2}{4}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n k^3 - \frac{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+1}{4}\leq 0$$

You definitely don't get $0\leq $ on the left after subtracting.

You get the bound:

$$\frac{n^4+2n^3+1}{4}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 \leq \frac{n^4+2n^3+3n^2+1}{4}$$

The actual value, $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$ is definitely between these two values.

Comment: You're right of course, but this doesn't bear at all on the invocation of the formula $\frac{1}{2}n^2(n+1)^2$. I believe the OP thinks the theorem should give that formula instead of a bound.

Comment: Well, OP thinks they are equal because if $0\leq A-B\leq 0$, then $A=B.$ @symplectomorphic

Comment: Oh! Yes, I see: I didn't realize the confusion went that far.